# Can Euclid's Elements be used to rigorously prove 2+2=4?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, ancient-philosophy

It is possible to formally prove that 2+2=4 using Peano's five axioms for the natural numbers and elementary set theory (actually a long and tedious process). Is it possible to prove it based on the definitions and axioms for numbers given in Euclid's Elements?

Comment: "Numbers are so familiar that it hardly occurs to us that the theory of numbers needs axioms, too. In fact, that field was one of the last to receive a careful scrutiny, and **axioms for numbers weren’t developed until the late 19th century** by Dedekind and others. By that time foundations for the rest of mathematics were laid upon either geometry or number theory or both, and **only geometry had axioms**." From http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html.

Comment: The question fits Math.SE best.

Comment: The proof of 2+2=4 in PA is only long and tedious in the same way that many people consider 2 miles a long distance to run: the only people who *care* about proving 2+2=4 (and a good number of people who do not) find it an easy jog down to the corner. Perhaps you had in mind Principia Mathematica?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I sketched an outline just now at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842314/prove-that-22-4/843213#843213

Comment: My comment still stands. This may not be the one-liner one might optimistically hope for elementary arithmetic, but anyone who has done propositional logic in a formal system can tell you that this is essentially short and sweet.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap The hard part is proving the existence of the add function. If you want to "cheat" and simply assume it's existence from the start, it is indeed a trivial exercise. It is reduced from several hundred lines of formal proof to no more than 10 lines.

Comment: I don't remember PA saying anything about functions being sets of tuples, or for that matter defining a set or a tuple. I think we're stuck defining a+0=a, a+S(b)=S(a+b). This certainly defines an action "+b" which one can perform on natural numbers a, for any b. Call that action "addition". Whether it is "a function" requires us to define what a function is, which for 2+2=4 is arguably beside the point.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap PA does not contain all the rules of inference. I have stated PA in the language of set theory and first-order logic. And I can derive other statements using the axioms and rules of set theory and logic. You can construct a unique add function in this way, as I have shown.

Comment: @DanChristensen: All I'm pointing out is that you use more machinery than needed. It suffices to use a formal system with symbols `∀∃=&v⇒¬():0S+×^` and countably many variables, where all but the last five symbols are used in the usual way as logical delimeters/connectives/etc. One defines the use of `0` and `S` by Peano's Axioms, and the meaning of the final three symbols are by the usual recursive formulae for addition/multiplication/exponentiation. Thus one may show that `SS0+SS0=SSSS0` concisely, without needing to use set theory, describe what a "function" or a "tuple" is, etc.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap The advantage of using set theory should be obvious. To develop number theory, you need only 5 axioms. You don't need to start with a definition of +, * and ^. You can construct these functions. If your set theory has some kind of axiom of infinity, you may actually be able to derive Peano's axioms as in ZFC.

Comment: @DanChristensen: We're clearly talking past each other here. I'm just pointing out that however useful set theory is (and I'm not one to deny it), using it to model PA for the purposes of basic arithmetic proofs is like swatting a mosquito with a bulldozer: you can do it completely formally with much less. But as I now see in your original post that you clearly stipulate "... and elementary set theory", I'll stop here.

Comment: It is worth noting that the axioms in The Elements are not strong enough to do geometry. Euclid had to wave hands over some important issues, which he thought were common sense or did not require proof. Hilbert gave a full axiomatization of Euclidean geometry to repair these points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the issue of *Euclidean Arithmetic*, see by Ian Mueller, [Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid's Elements](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486453006) (1981 - Dover reprint).

All Ch.2 is devoted to this topic; see page 58 :

> In books VII-IX Euclid develops the subject of arithmetic in almost complete isolation from the remainder of the *Elements*. [...] [In contrast to previous books, we] find no specifically arithmetic postulates in the *Elements*.

We have definitions regarding *numbers* in *Book VII* [see [Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html#defs)] :

> *Book VII : Definitions*
>
> **Definition 1** : A *unit* is that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is called one.
>
> **Definition 2** : A *number* is a multitude composed of units.
>
> **Definition 3** : A number is a *part of* a number, the less of the greater, when it measures the greater;
>
> **Definition 4** : But *parts* when it does not measure it.
>
> **Definition 5** : The *greater number* is a multiple of the less when it is measured by the less. [...]

But there ara **no** Axioms; see Mueller, page 59 :

> Euclid does not prove that 2+2=4 or that a 2 and a 2 combined yield a 4, nor does he even have the apparatus for doing so. Such facts, insofar as they are used in the *Elements*, are used without proof.